# mySQL - User's total points count in different ranges

Tags: mysql, fetch

I want to list the user points count in different ranges

**User points table structure**

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-------------------+----------------+
| ID            | int(11)      | NO   | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id       | int(11)      | NO   | NULL              |                |
| points        | int(11)      | NO   | NULL              |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-------------------+----------------+
```

**Example data**

```
+----------------------+
| ID    user_id points |
|----------------------|
| 1     14      5      |
| 2     15      10     |
| 3     5       14     |
| 4     3       20     |
| 5     14      10     |
| 6     15      17     |
| 7     5       61     |
| 8     14      81     |
| 9     15      12     |
| 10    3       47     |
| 11    15      10     |
| 12    14      17     |
| 13    3       27     |
| 14    5       18     |
| 15    3       4      |
+----------------------+
```

**Total points count (Group by user)**

```
+---------+---------------+
| user_id | total_points  |
+---------+---------------+
| 3       | 98            |
| 5       | 91            |
| 14      | 108           |
| 15      | 49            |
+---------+---------------+
```

**Preferred output**

```
+--------+-------+
| Range  | Count |
+--------+-------+
| 0-50   | 01    |
| 50-100 | 02    |
| 100-150| 01    |
| > 150  | 00    |
+--------+-------+
```

How could I achieve that result in pure mySQL ?

Comment: If you rename the dynamic Count column to something (say `total_points`), then you can do `GROUP BY (total_points / 50)` to do what you need, I believe...

Comment: Did you attempt? if so post your query..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   CASE
     WHEN points <= 50 THEN '0-50'
     WHEN points BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN '51-100'
     WHEN points BETWEEN 101 AND 150 THEN '101-150'
     ELSE '> 150'
   END AS `Range`
   ,COUNT(*) AS `Count`
   ,CASE
     WHEN points <= 50 THEN 1
     WHEN points BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 2
     WHEN points BETWEEN 101 AND 150 THEN 3
     ELSE 4
   END AS `Sort`
FROM (
     SELECT user_id, SUM(points) as points
     FROM tbl
     GROUP BY user_id
     ) AS summary
GROUP BY `Range`, `Sort`
```

Comment: Urs is static one, but +1 for accurate answer to question